# How to export public key from Certificate Signing Request?

Tags: certificate, openssl

I wrote Android code to generate an RSA key pair and a certificate signing request.

Here is my CSR content:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I found a [tool](https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html) that can decode my CSR file:

[image: Screenshot of common name, organization, and organization unit as parsed by the CSR decoder at sslshopper.com]

How can I use OpenSSL to export the pubic key from this CSR file to `publickey.pem`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To output only the public key to a local file named `publickey.pem`:
`openssl req -in csr.txt -noout -pubkey -out publickey.pem`

You can view the (PEM-encoded) key on the terminal without putting it in a file by dropping the last argument:
`openssl req -in csr.txt -noout -pubkey`

Note: the `-noout` option is required, as by default the entire CSR will be placed in the output file, while your question asks for the public key only.

Bonus points: To look inside the BASE64-encoded PEM output and see the actual public key in hex format, pipe it to the `pkey` function of openssl:
`openssl req -in csr.txt -noout -pubkey | openssl pkey -pubin -noout -text`

Comment: `Note: the -noout option is required, as by default the entire CSR will be placed in the output file, while your question asks for the public key only.`
only answer out there that explains what this flag is doing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

`openssl req -in file.csr -pubkey -out pubkey.pem`